# Check Cognito Form for duplicate entries and reject

Tags: cognito-forms

Is there a way in Cognito Forms to check for duplicate entries & reject users submitting multiple entries?

Answer (score 1):

[Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) does not currently support restricting submissions by IP address or other means to prevent someone from submitting multiple entries on a form.  However, this is something we are considering, so please up vote and comment on this feature on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/6jZYx6eV).